# spring cloud gateway forward client certificate

Tags: ssl, spring-cloud, client-certificates, api-gateway, ssl-client-authentication

I am trying to use spring-cloud-gateway for a spring-boot based service that uses ssl with client-auth.

The problem is, calling the service from a client over the api-gateway always fails with "certificate_unknown" (works fine without the gateway).

It seem that the spring-cloud-gateway not forwarding the client certificate to the backend-service.

Any ideas how to achieve this? 
Is this a missing feature?

thx

Comment: The netty `HttpClient` needs to be configured to send the certificates. You can create a bean and configure it.

Comment: @spencergibb could you please provide some link showing how to configure Netty HttpClient to send the certificates?

Comment: I don't have any.

Comment: This is giving me some serious trouble as well. Have there been any solutions? This seems like a troubling flaw in the SGC.

Comment: hey @AndrewTFinnell did you ever reslove this? thanks for any info

Comment: The example here helped me on my way: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/640#issuecomment-478738139